# How to replace text of a specific line in a .txt file with Qt?

Tags: qt

I have this "data.txt" with this text inside:

```
1;Bob;Patino;43
/2;Chris;Metsen;46
/3;Rob;Pardo;37
/4;Megan;Fox;25
/5;Cara;Delevingne;21
```

And I want to replace the text of the second line "Metsen" for "Metzen".
I can do it by rewriting the whole data and it would be easy but maybe not convenient for tons of data.

Is there a way to do it by rewriting just that specific data (ideally using `QFile` and `QTextStream`) ?

Comment: Well, in that particular case, you can just seek to the s and write a z in its place, but in an arbitrary replacement scenario it won't be that simple, plus there is text encoding, it is not a raw byte array, so you will likely need to read the entire file to a string, do any replacements and then rewrite the file.

Comment: `QRegExp` could be your friend.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus can you example it applied to QFile and QTextStream?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo - regex will not help you with that, only with replacing text in a string

Comment: @driver are you saying a .txt file can't be read as a string and parsed with regular expressions?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus are you sure you will not need to rewrite the entire data with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds from your question that you want to do the replacement in memory-mapped IO, which is not going to be possible, in the general case. What happens if the file isn't ASCII encoded, or if the replacement text isn't the same size as the text it replaces? As soon as you need an 'insert' operation you are rewriting the whole file whether you like it or not. Additionally, the file still has to be completely *read* in order to search the text, so it wouldn't end up being much of an optimization anyway. Modern disc drives have write speeds of hundreds to thousands of Megabytes per second, so your write time is probably negligible.

Not to mention you are almost 100% certainly going to corrupt your original data while trying to debug the program. Even if you do it right, if the process were to die you'd also corrupt the original data. It's not the right approach.

That said, simple substring replacements *can* be performed using regular expressions with `QFile` and `QTextStream`. This program reads in `data.txt`, corrects the spelling errors, and writes the results to a new file called `newData.txt`.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QRegularExpressionMatch>
#include <QRegularExpressionMatchIterator>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QFile data("C:/workspace/simpleQtProject/data.txt");
    data.open(QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString dataText = data.readAll();

    QRegularExpression re("Metsen");
    QString replacementText("Metzen");

    dataText.replace(re, replacementText);

    QFile newData("C:/workspace/simpleQtProject/newData.txt");
    if(newData.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)) {
        QTextStream out(&newData);
        out << dataText;
    }
    newData.close();

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* Optimized performance of `QRegularExpression` is actually really good, but debuging can be slow due to the JIT compiler being disabled in debug mode. See [peppe's blog post](https://dangelog.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/qregularexpression/) for a good discussion on the nuances of the implementation (and benchmarks of the release performance).

Additionally, if your regex's become more complex, and you need finer grain control over how the replacements are performed, you can use the `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator` syntax, and the index-based `QString::replace()`. This could support multiple or named capture groups, or other advanced regex features.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QRegularExpressionMatch>
#include <QRegularExpressionMatchIterator>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QFile data("C:/workspace/simpleQtProject/data.txt");
    data.open(QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString dataText = data.readAll();

    // Using regex match iterator. Overkill for simple substring replacement, but scalable
    // to very complex replacements.
    QRegularExpression re("Metsen");
    QString replacementText("Metzen");

    QRegularExpressionMatchIterator itr = re.globalMatch(dataText);

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = itr.next();
        dataText.replace(match.capturedStart(0), match.capturedLength(0), replacementText);
    }

    QFile newData("C:/workspace/simpleQtProject/newData.txt");
    if(newData.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)) {
        QTextStream out(&newData);
        out << dataText;
    }
    newData.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for having clarified my issue .
The second solution helps me a lot with my project, ty so much for that too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution that works for me. I read out the whole file into a StringList. Then I search for the line and then I write everything back.

```
  QFile fTextFile("text.TXT");
  if(fTextFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
  {
        QTextStream tStream(&fTextFile);
        tStream.setCodec("UTF-8");
        //write Text into QStringList
        while(!tStream.atEnd())
        {
            sFileAsList.append(tStream.readLine());
        }

        //Check if FileList is empty
        if (sFileAsList.isEmpty())
        {
            fTextFile.close();
            return false;
        }

        //search for specific line and change it
        for (int i = 0; i < sFileAsList.size(); ++i)
        {
           QString line = sFileAsList[i];
           //for me that search was enough. 
           //But you can search or iterate  
           //through the QStringList as you wish...
            if(line.left( 6 ) == "CHANGE")
            {
                sFileAsList[i] = "newText";
            }
        }

        //Rewrite QStringList into Textfile
        tStream.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < sFileAsList.size(); ++i)
        {
            fTextFile.write(sFileAsList[i].toUtf8() + "\n");
        }

        fTextFile.close();
     }

     return true;
```